# Can I do it with one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

```
SELECT `invites`.`id`, `invites`.`from`, `invites`.`to`, `invites`.`group_id`
FROM `invites`
WHERE `invites`.`to` = '33'
```

It gets ID of user that sent invite and ID of user that is invited. And, of course, ID of group they invited each other. I need to display usernames of them, but they are stored in another table. The same goes for groups. Info about them is stored in another table.

I could make new queries to get that info from IDs, but is it worth it? Can I do it with only one query?

**Edit:**

Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);

CREATE TABLE `invites` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `from` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `to` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A join is always worst it:

```
SELECT `invites`.`id`, 
       `invites`.`from`, 
       `invites`.`to`, 
       `invites`.`group_id`,
       `toUsers`.`name` as toUserName,
       `fromUsers`.`name` as fromUserName,
       `groups`.`name` as groupName
FROM `invites`
    INNER JOIN `users` AS toUsers
        ON `invites`.`to` = toUsers.id
    INNER JOIN `users` AS fromUsers
        ON `invites`.`from` = fromUsers.id
    INNER JOIN `groups`
        ON `invites`.`group_id` = `groups`.`id`
WHERE `invites`.`to` = '33'
```

The only thing you have to keep in mind is to have foreign keys on `from`, `to` and `group_id`, and have primary keys on `Id` in tables Users and Groups. Then your query will be as fast as you need.

So I advise to run this :

```
ALTER TABLE `invites`
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_invites_to FOREIGN KEY (`to`) REFERENCES users(id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_invites_from FOREIGN KEY (`from`) REFERENCES users(id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_invites_group FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES groups(id)
```

See some doc : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: I added structure of my table. I don't have two user tables as u assume!

Comment: @dagrevis He didn't assume you have two user tables. He joins the same user table twice using different aliases (`toUsers` and `fromUsers`).

Comment: You can join multiple times with the same table. What you need to do is join one time with users for the 'to' part, and one time for the 'from part'. Then there are just aliases, but this is the same Users table.

Comment: Doesn't this "`toUsers`.`name` as toUserName" mean that I need to have `toUsers` table?

Comment: Nop, it is just using the alias of the first join table 'users', when you have `INNER JOIN users AS toUsers`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29):

```
SELECT invites.id, invites.from, invites.to, invites.group_id, group.name, u1.name, u2.name
FROM invites, user as u1, user as u2, group
WHERE invites.from = u1.id
AND invites.to = u2.id
AND group.id = invites.group_id
AND invites.to = '33'
```

Assuming your tables are called `user` and `group` and your fields `name`. You may have to put the backticks back on the field names because `FROM` is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a join too, but I'd create a view first that joins invites to users, then join two of those together - it means not having to repeat the join between invite and user.